# UITextfield width does not get change

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I have an iPhone/iPad app supporting both orientation, and I have set te width of UItableView cell content also, but when I change device orientation from landscape to portrait UITextfield width (some of) remains constant what they were in lanscape.

screen shots are : [image: Landscape View]

and after device orientation change some of UITextfield shows as : 
[image]

so what is the solution for it?

Comment: Post some code, hard to say anything without.

Comment: try to use auto layout.

Comment: But I am doing it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Check for Autoresizing masks in xib

Comment: I am doing it programmatically.

Comment: Even if you creating it programatically still there are some default autoresizing masks were assigned to it.. Try setting your autoresizing mask programatically..